# Using double quotation

Tags: grammar, meaning, words

So, in a NHK news article I encountered the following  sentence:

> > 菅総理大臣は緊急宣言の下で異例の開催となると指摘しこれまでの緊急宣言となれば無観客も辞さないと申し上げてきたと述べた上で

With this 申し上げてきた is the prime minster talking about himself and his instruction to the officials, and is the と述べる said by the News caster to quote what he stated as a whole?

Comment: これまでの or これまでも？

Comment: これまでの is the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is parsed like:

> 菅総理大臣は「(1)～～」と指摘し「(2)～～」と述べた
> Prime Minister Suga pointed out "(1)＿＿" and told "(2)＿＿".

And the two quotes are:

> 1. 緊急宣言の下で異例の開催となる
>    This is going to be an unusual event held under the emergency declaration
> 2. これまでも緊急宣言となれば無観客も辞さないと申し上げてきた
>    I have always said (to you, the media) that we are willing to go without an audience if we declare an emergency

I could not find the original NHK article, but if it really says これまで**の**, it should be a mere typo for これまで**も**.

申しあげる is a humble verb which never appears in the main body of a news article. Thus we can assume 申しあげてきた is inside a quote even without explicit quotation marks. Besides, as a humble verb, 申しあげる is used to raise the status of the listener. Here the "listener" is the media that has interviewed the prime minister, not his subordinates.